# How can I access a Run Setting -> Context Parameter from code in a class inheriting from WebTest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

VS2013, I have a load test.  I want to be able to run this load test in a variety of environments i.e. dev, staging, production.  I would like to be able to pass some environment specific information at run time such as server url, login info etc.  So I was thinking either configuration or context parameters.  I can find plenty of information on how to add a context parameter ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406971(v=vs.120).aspx ) but none on how to access said parameter.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Are context parameters the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with to add "configuration" to a VS load test is using context parameters. To do this you will need to:

1. Add context parameters (right clicking on the desired run setting).
2. Then, in order to be able to access these parameters through coded
   WebTests, you need to create a load test plugin class (See plugin class below).
3. Lastly you need to add this plugin to the loadtest (right click on the root node of the load test).

This class will add all of the active run setting's context parameters your coded WebTest.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting;

namespace VerificationLoadTest
{
    public class ContextParameterLoadTestPlugin : ILoadTestPlugin
    {
        LoadTest LoadTest;
        public void Initialize(LoadTest loadTest)
        {
            this.LoadTest = loadTest;
            this.LoadTest.TestStarting += new EventHandler<TestStartingEventArgs>(TestStarting);
        }

        void TestStarting(object sender, TestStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string key in LoadTest.Context.Keys)
            {
                e.TestContextProperties.Add(key, LoadTest.Context[key]);
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Once the project is compiled and the plugin added to the loadtest (step 3 above) the parameters can be access like this:

```
public class ContextParameterTest : WebTest
{
     public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
     {
          var serviceUrl = this.Context[ContextParamKey].ToString();
          WebTestRequest webTestRequest = new WebTestRequest(serviceUrl);

          ... build your request

          request.PostRequest += request_PostRequest;
          yield return request;
          request = null;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2015, which I don't think is much different in this aspect, **all** Load Test Context entries are available in C# through `WebTest.Context`, and do not require explicit adding via a plugin.  You can also access just the Load Test Context via `LoadTest.Context` when in a Load Test plugin.

I've found debugging tests to be invaluable when investigating these types of issues.  Load Tests, Web Tests (*.webtest), and Coded Web Tests (through the context menu) all support a Debug action in addition to Run.  This will honor your breakpoints and allow you to poke around all the members of the `WebTest` instance.  If you're not using Coded Web Tests, you'll have to have C# code somewhere to put a breakpoint, e.g. through a custom plug-in, extractor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided includes the words

> ... if the Web performance test in the load test uses the same context parameter name as a context parameter in the load test, the context parameter in the load test will override the context parameter that is used in the Web performance test

Context parameters can be used in many places within a web test by enclosing then in doubled curly braces. Eg the value in a context parameter, say `MyContextParameter`, can be used in a URL or a query string etc with the style `{{MyContextParameter}}` also `some text {{MyContextParameter}} and more text`.

Context parameters can be read out in a web test plugin or a web test request plugin by using the `e.WebTest.Context` field, where `e` is the `...EventArgs` parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you say here is true.  ContextParameters set in the UI of a loadTests RunSettings are NOT available in a coded WebTest without the use of a plugin as I described above.  I had no use for a plugin, the only reason I created it was because it was the only way I could find to get my ContextParameters copied over.

Comment: @goyo Just checked with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. From the context menu of the run settings (eg `Run Settings1`) added a context parameter with the same name as one in a web test, but different values. The web test's parameter is overridden by that from the load test.